# Spring oauth2 authorization server add roles user in token

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0

I use spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server (v. 0.2.0) for implement my authorization-server.
I would like user roles to be in the token, is it possible to add them? like?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding the following bean

```
@Bean
OAuth2TokenCustomizer<JwtEncodingContext> jwtCustomizer() {
    return context -> {
        if (context.getTokenType() == OAuth2TokenType.ACCESS_TOKEN.getValue()) {
            Authentication principal = context.getPrincipal();
            Set<String> authorities = principal.getAuthorities().stream()
                    .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
            context.getClaims().claim("user-authorities", authorities);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be `==` check with `ACCESS_TOKEN` not the value.

```
@Bean
OAuth2TokenCustomizer<JwtEncodingContext> jwtCustomizer() {
    return context -> {
        if (context.getTokenType() == OAuth2TokenType.ACCESS_TOKEN) {
            Authentication principal = context.getPrincipal();
            Set<String> authorities = principal.getAuthorities().stream()
                    .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
            context.getClaims().claim("user-authorities", authorities);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For spring boot 3.0.3 and above,

```
 static class CustomAuthenticationConverter implements Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> {
        public AbstractAuthenticationToken convert(Jwt jwt) {
            Collection<String> authorities = jwt.getClaimAsStringList("roles");
            Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = authorities.stream().map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            return new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, grantedAuthorities);
        }
    }
```

and add the following code in the `securityFilterChain`

```
http.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
                .jwt(jwt -> jwt
                        .jwtAuthenticationConverter(new CustomAuthenticationConverter())
                    )
                );
```

Refer https://github.com/m-thirumal/oauth-resource-server